# How to move up the XML `Element` one step higher and change its `XName` to this format `parent_child` using `Linq to XML` in C#

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

I am trying to modify the following XML doc (MRE) using `Linq to XML`:

1. Move the school name and address one step higher or at the level of its parent—school element.
2. At the same time, change its name to `<School_Name>` and `<School_Address>`.

**ORIGINAL**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GreatGrandParent>
      <GrandParent>
        <Parent>
          <Child>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Address>California</Address>
            <Sex>Male</Sex>
            <Age>18</Age>
            <School>
              <Name>Cool School</Name>
              <Address>California</Address>
            </School>
          </Child>
          <Child>
            <Name>Mary</Name>
            <Address>New Orleans</Address>
            <Sex>Female</Sex>
            <Age>16</Age>
            <School>
              <Name>Pretty School</Name>
              <Address>New Orleans</Address>
            </School>
          </Child>
        <Parent>
      <GrandParent>
    <GreatGrandParent>
```

**TARGET MODIFICATION**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GreatGrandParent>
      <GrandParent>
        <Parent>
          <Child>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Address>California</Address>
            <Sex>Male/Sex>
            <Age>18</Age>
            <School_Name>Cool School</School_Name>
            <School_Address>California</School_Address>
          </Child>
          <Child>
            <Name>Mary</Name>
            <Address>New Orleans</Address>
            <Sex>Female/Sex>
            <Age>16</Age>
            <School_Name>Pretty School</School_Name>
            <School_Address>New Orleans</School_Address>
          </Child>
        <Parent>
      <GrandParent>
    <GreatGrandParent>
```

**HERE'S WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

```cs
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Xml\Childs Profile.xml");
    XElement root = doc.XPathSelectElement("//Parent");
    IEnumerable<XElement> rootlists = root.Descendants("Child").ToList();
        
    foreach (var rootlist in rootlists)
    {
        XElement lists = root.Element("Child");
    
        XElement name = root.Element("Child").Element("School").Element("Name");
        XElement address = root.Element("Child").Element("School").Element("Address");
    
        list.AddFirst(name);
        list.AddFirst(address);
    
        XElement school = root.Element("Child").Element("School");
        school.Remove();
    }
    doc.Save(@"D:\Xml\Childs Profile.xml");
```

- **ISSUES:** The `foreach` above does not move to next child.
- **PENDING:** Change the `XName` to `<School_Name>` and    `<School_Address>` either before or after moving.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"the.xml");

var child = doc.Descendants("Child");
var school = child.Elements("School");

string name = $"{school.First().Name}_{school.Elements("Name").First().Name}";
string address = $"{school.First().Name}_{school.Elements("Address").First().Name}";

foreach (var s in school)
{
    s.Parent.Add(new XElement(name, s.Element("Name").Value));
    s.Parent.Add(new XElement(address, s.Element("Address").Value));
}

school.Remove();

doc.Save(@"out.xml");
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?